# Error with database - "Value cannot be null. Arg_ParamName_Name"

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

I do a project in ASP.NET Core 6.0 and try to connect a database.

Program.cs:

```
using ClanSS.Data;
using ClanSS.Data.Repository;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IRepository, Repository>();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
   { 
       options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
   });

var app = builder.Build();

if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllerRoute(name: "default", pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
app.Run();
```

AppDbContext.cs

```
using ClanSS.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace ClanSS.Data
{
    public class AppDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options)
         : base(options)
        { Database.EnsureCreated(); }
        public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; } 
        public DbSet<Player> Team { get; set; }
    }
}
```

appsettings.json:

```
{
"DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=u0925467_myblog;Trusted_Connection=true;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
}
```

When I launch the project, the string in Startup is highlighted: `options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));`. And the follow error is shown:

> Value cannot be null. Arg_ParamName_Name

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your AppSetting.json should be like this :

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
      "DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=u0925467_myblog;Trusted_Connection=true;MultipleActi 
       veResultSets=true"
  },
```

Comment: Thank you for attention, but, unfortunately, it doesn't help

Comment: @Toshik when you use Configuration.GetConnectionString() it looks for a property called ConnectionStrings in appSetting.json which is missing in this case. You can use this instead: builder.Configuration["DefaultConnection"]

Answer (score 0):

This should be an error caused by not being able to get your `DefaultConnection`, it may be that your `ConnectionStrings` are in the wrong location.

appsetting.json should look like this：

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=u0925467_myblog;Trusted_Connection=true;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  }
}
```